# How to query Index and selector using ektorp Java API

Tags: cloudant

I am using ektorp 1.4.1 Jar to connect to Cloudant database. Now I am able to write map and reduce functions using class EventRepository extends CouchDbRepositorySupport. But my problem here is, how I can query for Index and Selector using ektorp java API? Please help me out here by any one. Thanks in advance.

This is my Query Index :

```
{
  "index": {
    "fields": [
      {"name": "userName", "type": "string"}
    ]
  },
  "type": "text"
}
```

and here is my selector code for getting all Events from cloudant by User Name Descending order by startDate.

```
{
  "selector": {
    "userName": "vekusuma@in.ibm.com" 
  },
  "fields": [
    "userName",
    "startDate",
    "days",
    "_id",
    "_rev"
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "userName": "desc"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

I am using the below code to connect cloudant using Cloudant java API...

```
CloudantClient client = ClientBuilder.url(new URL("https://userName:password@*****.cloudant.com")).username("*******").
password("*******").build();             
List<String> dbsList = client.getAllDbs();
System.out.println("...dbsList size is :: " + dbsList.size());

CloudantClient client = ClientBuilder.account("username").username("username").password("password").
build();
```

but still same issue...
and even I have tried in different way...

... and I am getting below mentioned error while running on Eclipse Websphere server 7.0 on local...

***********Error*************
[3/9/16 23:53:43:547 IST] 00000031 SystemErr     R com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbException: 400 Bad request:

## 400 Bad request

Your browser sent an invalid request.
[3/9/16 23:53:43:548 IST] 00000031 SystemErr     R    at com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.execute(CouchDbClient.java:501) 
Plz help me some thing here... Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the full stack trace? Are you using the latest version of the cloudant java library?

Answer (score 0):

From my (quick) reading of the [ektorp API](http://ektorp.org/reference_documentation.html), it doesn't support Cloudant Query, (the product name for query). However there is a [Official Cloudant java library](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant) which does support the Cloudant Query endpoints.

Comment: Ok... Thanks for your Information.. I have tried Cloudant Library as well with the 1.3 version... I think above 2.0 versions is not free ware and we need to buy license from them... Is it freeware or not? pzl let me know how to do the same above functionality by using java Cloudant API with 1.4 version jar file?

Comment: The cloudant library is free, it's also open source (Apache 2.0). I'm not sure where you got the information about them not being free, so if you could point me at that I can get it fixed. The [documentation for 2.3](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.cloudant/cloudant-client/2.3.0) on using Cloudant Query, it should give you enough information to get started.

Comment: I am also from IBM only... I got your ID.... plz let me know your timings that when u will be coming to online daily. So will message u the error message directly there. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you want email support, e-mail support@cloudant.com

Comment: Hi rhyshort... I edited my original post and posted the error messages there. plz check it once. Thanks :)